# Installing the slideshow plugin with CKEditor

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm using CKEditor 4.5.6.91 with [Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) and [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg). I've tried the following:

- Installing the Slideshow plugin to CKEditor by following the directions on the [Slideshow plugin page exactly](http://devlabnet.eu/softdev/slideshow/index.php) (that is, download it to the `plugins/` folder, then add `CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'slideshow';`. This didn't work because I never got any kind of "slideshow" checkbox in the WYSIWYG settings.
- I also tried downloading a custom version of CKEditor that has the Slideshow plugin already installed with it. Same problem as above.
- Then I tried using  `hook_wysiwyg_plugin()` to create the checkbox. Now I'm getting the error in the js console, `Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "slideshow" was not found at "/sites/all/modules/my_module/ckeditor/slideshow/dialogs/slideshow.js/plugin.js?t=FB9E".` Here's the full code:

> ```
> function mymodule_wysiwyg_plugin($editor, $version) {
>   switch ($editor) {
>    case 'ckeditor':
>     return array(
>      'slideshow' => array(
>       'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/ckeditor/slideshow/dialogs/slideshow.js',
>       'buttons' => array(
>        'slideshow' => t('Slideshow'),
>       ),
>       'load' => TRUE,
>      ),
>     );
>     break;
>   }
>  }
> ```

I've tried giving the path to both `slideshow/dialogs/slideshow.js` and `slideshow/plugin.js` and in both cases got the same error.

I've run out of ideas of what to do to make the slideshow button appear and be functional in the CKEditor.

Comment: [Here is how I have installed CK Editor plugins](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186086/installing-extra-additional-plugins-for-standalone-ckeditor-module-library/186099#answer-186099)

Comment: I don't have the option to use the CKEditor module instead of the WYSIWYG module because I need to have the media_wysiwyg module for other things.