# Custom ckeditor library plugins not showing

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, theming

I created a custom ckeditor library from [Ckeditor Builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder). I am using the latest version. I tried this library with both [ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) and [wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module.

When I go to ckeditor settings in admin, I only see basic options and do not see the plugins I added to my custom ckeditor on the ckeditor website.

Comment: I think it is not a duplicate because I am talking about a complete custom library

Comment: You have to integrate the plugins, they won't just appear by adding them to the ckeditor build.

Comment: I have partly addressed why dropping plugins into a build don't show in this answer before: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223171/57